# "material flung", "drawn across its orbit"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The following quote is from "The Mars Mystery" by Graham Hancock.

> "The best suggestion is that the material flung at Mars was drawn across its orbit because of 'perturbations and collisions of bodies in the asteroid belt' probably caused by the atmospheric attraction of Jupiter".

The author is talking about possible causes of dichotomy on Mars, e.g the northern hemisphere is three kilometers lower. It's a pleasure to follow the clear and concise way of thinking of Graham Hancock. However, in the quote, I stumbled when I tried to imagine the description.

Is it said that:

1) Jupiter's [atmosphere] attraction caused the asteroids [from the asteroid belt, parts or the wholes] to collide, disintegrate, and fall onto the northern hemisphere of Mars.

2) Thrown mass of material of Mars (called 'material flung'), as a result of numerous bombardments of only the northern hemisphere, started orbiting Mars or joined the asteroid belt.

I must confess that I have no idea what 'drawn across its orbit' might mean here if I tried to apply my rudimentary knowledge of astronomy.

Comment: In short, Mars was bombarded by material. That material had to cross Mars' orbit in order for it to be captured by Mars' gravity well and ultimately impact the planet. What accounts for this material being in Mars' orbit in the first place? Well, it was happily sitting around in the asteroid belt, content to orbit for eternity, but then Jupiter's own attraction caused some bodies in the asteroid belt to get shuffled around, knock into other bodies, and after a long game of pinball (or dominoes), some material was ejected out f the belt and ultimately found itself in Mars's orbit and then *bam*

Comment: *Draw* = *pull*

Comment: @Dan: A slight elaboration on your excellent comment, which should be an answer. When two gravitationally attracting bodies come close, they perturb each other's orbits, so the asteroids don't actually have to physically collide to play pinball – just coming close is good enough (like horseshoes and hand grenades). This is why the quote reads "perturbations and collisions".

Comment: I'm utterly confused. I got it all wrong! I was sure 'material' was Martian because shortly before the author states that there is no big enough sink on Mars for sculpted crust.

Comment: @PeterShor Valid point. I was thinking "gravitational pinball" in my head, but I didn't make that clear at all in my comment. And you know I'm too lazy to make an answer with references and details and all. You're welcome to turn my comment into an answer if you like.

Comment: It really says "atmospheric attraction of Jupiter, not gravitational attraction? What is atmospheric attraction? I would have thought that bodies close enough to Jupiter to be affected by its atmosphere would have little chance of reaching Mars. But I'm not a scientist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a clearly worded extract! The problematic phrase "drawn across its orbit" is not really appropriate, and I understand the confusion.

"To draw" something is, as per [dictionary.reference.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw), to pull it (or at least to make it seem as if it's being pulled):

> to cause to move in a particular direction by or as if by a pulling force; pull; drag (often followed by along, away, in, out, or off)

The [orbit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/orbit?s=t) of a planet is:

> the curved path, usually elliptical, described by a planet, satellite, spaceship, etc., around a celestial body, as the sun

Hence the material was "pulled into the path of Mars". The reason this is poor wording is that this material has just been described as "flung at Mars", where "[to fling](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fling?s=t)" is:

> to throw, cast, or hurl with force or violence

So "the material flung at Mars was drawn across its orbit" means:

> the material thrown at Mars was pulled into the path of Mars

which is nonsensical. Was it thrown at Mars? Or was it pulled into the path of Mars such that Mars hit it? The two seem contradictory to me, but overall we can interpret it as "the material which collided with Mars".

The rest of the extract doesn't seem so problematic. A full explanation (attempting to go clause for clause):

*original*

> 1. The best suggestion is that
> 2. the material flung at Mars
> 3. was drawn across its orbit
> 4. because of 'perturbations and collisions of bodies in the asteroid belt'
> 5. probably caused by the atmospheric attraction of Jupiter

*reworded*

> 1. The best suggestion is that
> 2. the material **which collided with** Mars
> 3. was **in the path of Mars**
> 4. because of **asteroids in the asteroid belt moving about and knocking each other into different paths**
> 5. **the reason the asteroids were moving about was** probably **that they were disturbed by the gravitational field** of Jupiter

---

Technical note: This was written by someone with a scant knowledge of astronomical physics. As per a comment from Peter Shor the description of asteroids "knocking each other" isn't strictly accurate:

"When two gravitationally attracting bodies come close, they perturb each other's orbits, so the asteroids don't actually have to physically collide to play pinball – just coming close is good enough (like horseshoes and hand grenades). This is why the quote reads "perturbations and collisions"."

Comment: Is there intent here? Where the material was flung by some sapient actor, and its intent was to hit Mars, but space-things 'caused it to go off course?

Comment: @Malandy - No. I don't see any need for a sapient actor in order to use the word "flung". I also don't see any sense in your suggestion that the intent was to hit Mars but the material hit Mars instead...